# AdMob Adserving disabled from my application

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

The Reason is the interstitial ad is on wrong way.
Can someone tell me Is there a problem with my interstitial?
Where to put it?
My code from where interstitial is:

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,
onWelComeButtonClickListener, OnClickListener {
    MatrixCursor cursor;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    ListView channelListView;

    ChannelCustomAdapter adapter;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    CharSequence title;
    Bundle bundle;
    Menu menu;
    RelativeLayout rlDrawerOpen;
    Typeface selectFonts;
    TextView tFacebook, tRateus;

    AdRequest fullScreenAdRequest;
    InterstitialAd fullScreenAdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializer();
        dLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        channelListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        tFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        tRateus.setOnClickListener(this);



        enableAd();
    }


    private void enableAd() {
        // adding full screen add
        fullScreenAdd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        fullScreenAdd.setAdUnitId("a151b7d316a5c1d");
        fullScreenAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        fullScreenAdd.loadAd(fullScreenAdRequest);

        fullScreenAdd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {

                Log.i("FullScreenAdd", "Loaded successfully");
                fullScreenAdd.show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

                Log.i("FullScreenAdd", "failed to Load");
            }
        });

    }


    private void initializer() {
        actionBar = getActionBar();

        selectFonts = (Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"));
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dl_drawerLayout);
        rlDrawerOpen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_drawer_open);
        channelListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_channel_List);

        title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        tFacebook = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFacbook);
        tRateus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRateUs);

        adapter = new ChannelCustomAdapter(this, GlobalData.getInstance()
            .getArrChannels());
        channelListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
        R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                setTitle("Select Channel");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                setTitle(title);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);

    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            // use the query to search your data somehow

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        } else {

            fragmentSelector();

        }

    }

    private void fragmentSelector() {
        bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
        if (bundle == null) {
            Fragment fr = new WelcomeFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_content, fr).commit();

            setTitle(title);

            ((WelcomeFragment) fr).setOnWelComeButtonClickListener(this);

        } else {
            selectItem(bundle.getInt("POS"));
            setTitle(bundle.getString("NAME"));
        }

    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fr = new RadioFragment();

        bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("URL",
        GlobalData.getInstance().getArrChannels().get(position)
            .getUrl());
        bundle.putString("NAME",
        GlobalData.getInstance().getArrChannels().get(position)
            .getChannelName());
        bundle.putInt("POS", position);
        fr.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_content, fr).commit();
        title = GlobalData.getInstance().getArrChannels().get(position)
            .getChannelName();
        dLayout.closeDrawer(rlDrawerOpen);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        actionBar.setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search)
            .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                if (getPositionfromString(query) != -1) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this,
                    RadioService.class);
                    stopService(intent);
                    selectItem(getPositionfromString(query));
                    setTitle(query);
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No channel found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                String[] columnNames = {
                    "_id", "text"
                };
                cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);

                String[] temp = new String[2];
                // int id = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < GlobalData.getInstance().getArrChannels()
                    .size(); i++) {
                    if (GlobalData.getInstance().getArrChannels().get(i)
                        .getChannelName().toLowerCase()
                        .contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                        temp[0] = Integer.toString(i);
                        temp[1] = GlobalData.getInstance().getArrChannels()
                            .get(i).getChannelName();
                        cursor.addRow(temp);
                    }
                }
            String[] from = {
                "text"
            };
            int[] to = {
                R.id.text
            };
            SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            ActivityMain.this, R.layout.search_item, cursor, from,
            to, SimpleCursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);

            searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(cursorAdapter);

            return true;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new OnSuggestionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);

            searchView.setQuery(cursor.getString(1), true);

            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}

private int getPositionfromString(String chn) {

    for (int i = 0; i < GlobalData.getInstance().getArrChannels().size(); i++) {

        if (chn.contentEquals(GlobalData.getInstance().getArrChannels()
            .get(i).getChannelName())) {

            return i;

        }

    }
    return -1;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) return true;
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search) return true;
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.search).setVisible(!dLayout.isDrawerOpen(rlDrawerOpen));
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position,
long id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, RadioService.class);
    stopService(intent);
    selectItem(position);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onWelComeButtonClick() {
    dLayout.openDrawer(rlDrawerOpen);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.tvFacbook:
            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ShowFacebook.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.tvRateUs:
            String linkurl = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.global.danceradio";
            if (linkurl != null) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, linkurl);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sharing failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, everything looks normal. But there is no the rest of the code. Maybe you create an activity every second.
I would recommend you to write in [support of the admob](https://support.google.com/admob#topic=2740022) and clarify the issues. Maybe you're lucky and they will unblock you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can you add timer on this code?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en
Check admob support. they updated new photos for better explanation.